# Можно ли на гридах сделать разную высоту элементов?

Tags: css, css-grid

вопрос такой, можно ли сделать на гридах что бы высота была разная и они подстраивались друг под другом, если же это были бы флексы они принимали одинаковую высоту. А на гридах можно ли? Или надо грузить плагин на примере как mansory
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На гридах конечно можно. Но можно и на флексах, вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1064346/331312

Comment: Может поможет вам эта ссылка https://webformyself.com/sortirovka-i-vyravnivanie-elementov-v-grid-layout/